# Prevent a Task Scheduler to run at Windows Startup

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-tasks

To test the computer hardware, I have used Task Scheduler in Windows Server 2008 R2 to automatic reboot the computer direct after startup. 
I have now done many reboots to verify the hardware, and want to disable the reboot scheduler. I have done it before, but now I don't remember how I do it. 
I can start the computer in Safe mode. But in that mode, Task Scheduler is disabled. I wonder how I can disable the automatic reboot of Windows

Comment: Next time put a delay in before running the task. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the duplicated question. I solved it by deleting the file from %systemroot%\System32\Tasks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use schtasks from the command line? Not 100% sure if it will work in Safe Mode but worth a try.

SchTasks /Delete /TN “Your Task”

helpful article:  [How to Create, Modify and Delete Scheduled Tasks from the Command Line](http://www.howtogeek.com/51236/how-to-create-modify-and-delete-scheduled-tasks-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: I get network address is invalid